# QML Canvas: problem with drawing of SVG image with lines containing arrows

Tags: qt, svg, qml

In QML canvas, I am trying to draw an image which is in svg format and contains lines with arrow heads like below.

[image]

svg in not supported by stackoverflow, so I put the png of svg image above just for diplay.

original svg is here : https://svgshare.com/i/9u8.svg

And when I tried to draw this image in QML canvas, resulted image doesn't  contain the arrow heads. The result look similar to below. Even in Qt creator, arrow heads are not shown.

[image]

I want to know is it problem with SVG generation or problem with drawing on canvas?

Comment: This svg also doesn't display the arrowheads when put in an `Image { }` component.

Comment: I've tried that and doesn't show arrows for me. Moreover, I have some plugin that shows svg in Windows explorer and that doesn't show arrows too. If you will open the file in a test editor you will see lots of external links, I guess that a problem. Try to remove all the external links.

Comment: I have created the svg using Inkscape, and the file is view properly in the online svg viewer here https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that Qts SVG implementation is based on TinySVG - it only supports a subset of SVG and can't handle all features of the specification. Looking at the code of the SVG-file, it is propably the `<marker>` elements that are not supported.

A possible solution would be to either edit the image (with e.g. Inkscape) to convert these markers to normal paths or to create a bunch of PNGs of variing sizes and load them conditionally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to change stroke to path like mentioned from the link below. Its showing arrow heads but the scaling is not happening.(https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30567/how-to-put-arrows-along-a-path-in-inkscape)